# How to confine q-dialog within the scope of a child component and prevent it from spanning across the entire screen of the parent component?

Tags: css, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

English isn't my native language, and I apologize for any confusion.

Hi,

I want to display the Q-Dialog only within a specific component block

The current code displays it fullscreen like the first image

But I want it to appear like the second image.

I know I can achieve this using an iframe, but I want to use component import for easier development.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Best Regards.

picture1: https://imgur.com/rbKTqpu

picture2: https://imgur.com/89a4JPd

```
Demo.vue |
----------
<template>
  <div class="masklayer">
    <div v-if="isPreviewOpen" style="width: 600px; height: 800px">
      <FccPreview style="height: 100%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import FccPreview from "src/components/Fcc/FccTest.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
const isPreviewOpen = ref(true);
</script>

-------------
FccTest.vue |
-------------
<template>
  <div style="background-color: #f3f3f3">
    <q-btn name="close" @click="isUnHelpful = true"> testButton </q-btn>
    <q-dialog v-model="isUnHelpful" position="bottom" class="q-pa-none">
      <q-card style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%">
        <q-card-actions align="center" class="q-pa-md">
          <q-btn
            unelevated
            label="send"
            size="16px"
            style="background-color: #8baaaa; color: white"
            v-close-popup
            @click="handleButtonClick"
          />
        </q-card-actions>
      </q-card>
    </q-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const isUnHelpful = ref(false);
</script>
```